# Unexpected shutdowns Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, uefi

I have been using Xubuntu 16.04 for a long time now (Xubuntu for 4 years). My system is a dual boot with Windows 10, but I never use Windows.

Since the last two days my laptop, Asus Zenbook UX305, has been shutting down unexpectedly. The following is the sequence of events. (1) An unexpected shutdown, mostly while I am browsing the net using firefox. (2) To restart, I have to plug in the power chord, without which it does not restart. (3) When I do restart, it takes me to Windows 10. The fast boot option, which had been disabled, gets enabled on its own, and the boot sequence changes to give priority to Windows over Ubuntu. (4) After restart I have to Login to Windows, go to UEFI settings, disable Fast boot, change the boot sequence to give priority to Ubuntu over Windows. (5) Now when I switch on the machine, I see the grub screen as usual, and then boot into Ubuntu again and things work normally. (6) I need to change the date because the date gets messed up due to booting into Windows.

In the log file `/var/log/syslog` I notice that on two occasions just before shutdown the last command to be executed is `CRON[8349]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)`

I am happy to completely remove Windows 10 and/or UEFI and/or anything else related to Windows, but I wonder if that will create any problems in future. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unexpected shutdowns may have several causes, but almost all of them are hardware-related, not Ubuntu-related. Check /var/log/syslog for warnings in the seconds *before* the shutdown occurred. If there are no warnings, then your cause is hardware, not software. The two most common hardware causes are overheating and faulty power supply.

Comment: FYI: Xubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://xubuntu.org/release/16-04/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments. I ran smartmontools and the results of all the tests were (I don't remember the exact terms) either old age or pre-fail. So I guess it's time to buy a new laptop.